# Is there a way to use one worksheet as database to create a code based on the date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently working on a spreadsheet formula where 2 different codes would be generated. Here is the algorithm for the "code" to start with., but I don't know how to construct a proper excel function for it.

There are 10 digits to the code where the first 8 digits are just the date i.e. 20210328_ _
The final 2 digits are dependent on the previous records whether there are records with the same date. If so it would assign a two-digit number starting from 1 to differentiate the different records.

I have tried to use the below formula to achieve what I want but the part where it references the other spreadsheet is bothering me as I need it to be a flexible value where the value is referring to the last row of the spreadsheet. Is there a way to work around this without scripts? I am planning to deploy it on Google Sheets so App scripts solutions would also be workable but not preferable.

```
=IF(DAY(B2)=RIGHT(Data!A114,2),Data!A114+1,CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),TEXT(B2,"MM"),DAY(TODAY()),"01"))
```

FYI B2 is the date of input and Data!A114 is the part where I concern.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Kindly provide a dummy spreadsheet or at least a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
Formula(D3)=IF((TO_PURE_NUMBER(Concatenate(YEAR(A3), TEXT(A3,"MM"),DAY(A3))) - TO_PURE_NUMBER(Concatenate(YEAR(A2),TEXT(A2,"MM"),DAY(A2)))), (TO_PURE_NUMBER(CONCATENATE(TO_PURE_NUMBER(Concatenate(YEAR(A3), TEXT(A3,"MM"),DAY(A3))), "00"))) ,(D2+1))
```

The data for the dates starts in A3, and continues down.

Link to the Google Sheet I tried it on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bwukKFaEow4PysqcJLA9jqjKBLZcY8T1vTN5VpZo8F8/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Do you have the table of data you tried the formula on? I would like to have a go.